# Unable to start Weblogic after DB crash

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic12c

My database crashed unexpectedly as the containing VM was collapsed and in turn Weblogic server went down. Now I've installed database in new VM and recovered data into it. But now, I'm unable to start my Weblogic admin server. I guess it's unable to retrieve the data from OPSS tables. What should I do now to start my Weblogic? How can I make all the database related changes from old VM to new VM?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the state of your `AdminServer` after the crash, it may be that your server is still seen as 'running' by the `NodeManager`. Try the following:

In the `[weblogic_domain]/servers/AdminServer/tmp` folder check for an `AdminServer.lok` file. If this file exists and you are sure your instance isn't running (ie. Checked there are no `JVM` running) delete the `.lok` file and try to start the `AdminServer`.

If this still fails you can delete the entire contents of the `tmp` folder but also go to the `[weblogic_domain]/servers/AdminServer/data/nodemanager` folder and delete all the files there.

Try starting the `AdminServer` again.

If it still fails you'll need to review the `AdminServer` and `nodemanager` logs and post them here for further help.